# How to manage tracking events google analytcs (code and dashboard)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

I'd like to understand more about google analytics and I am study more about data analytcs to improve results in my websites and I saw about tracking events to track perfomance about my website, so I do not know if my code it works correctly and how can I see the results of clicks in dashboard analytcs ? Anybody Help me ?

This link contain the code track event (http://pastebin.com/5E9Jhdbw)

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original code copied out for convenience:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.list-nav a').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        return ga('send', $(this).text(), 'button', 'click', 'menu');
});
```

The event code needs to include the hit type of "event", and you have an extra parameter as well. So the event code should look something like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'some_category', 'some_action', 'some_label');
```